# What should the return type of Promise.race be? (Typescript)

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, react-typescript

For example in the code below, what should the type of response be? Typescript keeps giving me errors such as, Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'Promise'

```
const response: [what type???] = await Promise.race([
      apicall(),
      timeoutPromise(),
    ]);
```

Comment: [`Promise.race`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) returns a promise of the value from whichever promise resolves first, then you `await` that promise and get the value. So what do `apicall` and `timeoutPromise` return promises of?

Comment: What types do `apicall` and `timeoutPromise` return? The result would be `ReturnType<typeof apicall> | ReturnType<typeof timeoutPromise>` but it's hardly useful.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/w6BREw) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: If you are getting the error on the line you posted, then it has nothing to do with the return type of `Promise.race()`; it is indicating that the return type of `apicall()` or `timeoutPromise()` is `unknown`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript cannot be sure which promice will be resolved first or even any of them will be resolved at all. So you should provide a type to Promice.race:

```
type PromiseType1 = string
type PromiseType2 = string
const apicall = () => new Promise<PromiseType1>(() => {})
const timeoutPromise = () => new Promise<PromiseType2>(() => {})

const response = await Promise.race<PromiseType1 | PromiseType2>([
  apicall(),
  timeoutPromise(),
]);
```